# Convert hex to int

Tags: string, c++-cli, int, hex

I've seen lots of answers to this, but I cannot seem to get any to work. I think I'm getting confused between variable types. I have an input from NetworkStream that is put a hex code into a String^. I need to take part of this string, convert it to a number (presumably int) so I can add some arithemetic, then output the reult on the form. The code I have so far:

```cpp
String^ msg; // gets filled later, e.g. with "A55A6B0550000000FFFBDE0030C8"
String^ test;

//I have selected the relevant part of the string, e.g. 5A
test = msg->Substring(2, 2);

//I have tried many different routes to extract the numverical value of the
//substring. Below are some of them:

std::stringstream ss;
hexInt = 0;
//Works if test is string, not String^ but then I can't output it later.
ss << sscanf(test.c_str(), "%x", &hexInt);

//--------
sprintf(&hexInt, "%d", test);

//--------
//And a few others that I've deleted after they don't work at all.

//Output:
this->textBox1->AppendText("Display numerical value after a bit of math");
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Chris

Comment: That's not C++. There's no `String^` in C++. I believe this is C++/CLI, so I changed the tag to that. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That number seems a bit too big to fit in an int.

Comment: I only want two character sections of it, not the whole 28. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
String^ hex = L"5A";
int converted = System::Convert::ToInt32(hex, 16);
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) for the Convert static method used is on the MSDN.

You need to stop thinking about using the standard C++ library with managed types.  The .Net BCL is really very good...

Comment: That's perfect cheers. I didn't realise I was using c++ library.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
/*
the method demonstrates converting hexadecimal values,
which are broken into low and high bytes.
*/
int main(){ 
//character buffer
char buf[1];
buf[0]= 0x06; //buffer initialized to some hex value
buf[1]= 0xAE; //buffer initialized to some hex value
int number=0;  

//number generated by binary shift of high byte and its OR with low byte
number = 0xFFFF&((buf[1]<<8)|buf[0]);

printf("%x",number);              //this prints AE06
printf(“%d”,number);              //this prints the integer equivalent

getch();
}
```